# Vuejs3 + laravel 8 working find locally but in prod vuejs files throwing syntax error and view not render Uncaught SyntaxError: 59

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cpanel

build a project using Vuejs 3 in Laravel 8 went running on Laravel server it works well but went I run npm run prod and deploy it in Cpanel compilation fails with Uncaught SyntaxError: 59 in the console I have remove style and script tags from blade file but still have a problem. please I really need your help

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Comment: yeah, i host it without running "npm run prod"

Answer (score 2):

Please check your final html code. May be there you will find a `<style>...</style>` or `<script>...</script>` tags... These are the main problem of `Uncaught SyntaxError: 59`. Yes, it will be ignored in local and development environment but won't in production one...
For example:

```html
<div id="app">
    <script>
        alert('yes');
    </script>
</div>
```

The main idea to put script and style tags out of the `div#app` element.